# jQuery check server updates in a setInterval function - what else can be used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create the code which will check if e.g some new muser messages appeared and show its count. I know it's simple - just make an ajax calls in the `setInterval` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setInterval(function () {
        //create an ajax call
    }, 30000);

});
```

but it's not the point - I can't find any information of the other approaches. Is it the only way to achieve this by set the `setInterval` function to check the updates ?

### Edit

Ok, I've found http://socket.io/ maybe it's what I'm looking for

Comment: Don't use `setInterval`, use `setTimout` recursively.

Answer (score 4):

You could as well use setTimeout on callback, so that every time something comes back from the server it will set another timer for like 30 sec later. There are advantages of this (server won't be overloaded with your requests even if the response is slow) but also drawbacks (once there's no answer poll won't run again).

Also there are other ways of keeping an eye on the server; search for the term "long polling" in Google.

Comment: If you read the updated question and the other answer then you will see that 'Nope' is clearly a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest solution. Otherwise you should use sockets like http://socket.io which is more low level but in this way you could implement push messages to the client.

Here is a tutorial of a `nodejs` and `socket.io` push notification server: http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/nodejs-and-a-simple-push-notification-server/

And this is another one for `PHP`:
http://pusher.com/tutorials/html5_realtime_push_notifications